# How to identify which web server in a farm served a request?

Tags: iis, iis-7, load-balancing

We're debugging intermittent issues with a website running on IIS7.

Since we have many nodes behind the load balancer, we can't tell which host responded to a given request. Is there any way at the IIS level to specify which host served a request?
For example, could IIS append a header in the response that indicates the IP of the host that sent the response?

Ideally, I would like a solution that does not require any coding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without writing any code you could just configure a custom HTTP Response Header for each machine in IIS Manager. You'd need to manually enter each IP address or identifier manually using either the GUI or `APPCMD.EXE`. This can be done globally for all sites:

```
appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/httpProtocol 
              /+"customHeaders.[name='X-Custom-Name',value='MyCustomValue']"
```

Or for a single site:

```
appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site" -section:system.webServer/httpProtocol 
              /+"customHeaders.[name='X-Custom-Name',value='MyCustomValue']"
```

I've split these commands over two lines just to fit them in. You should enter them as a single line.